# Hiding and Showing content using strict HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, toggle, show-hide

I'm aware that you can you JavaScript/ jQuery to hide and show content in html using the toggle() function however, how would this be done in barebones HTML and CSS? If I had the following code?

```
<div class="story" id=part1">
    Part 1 of story
    <a href="#" id="button1">Click Here to go to Part 2</a>
</div>

<div class="story" id="part2">
    Part 2 of story
    <a href="#" id="button2">Click Here to go to Part 1</a>
</div>

#part2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: There is no css property to toggle the display property. You set it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this little trick without JavaScript, only css and html.

```css
.wrapper {
        height: 100px;
        width: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.story {
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#part1 {
    background-color: green;
}

#part2 {
    margin-top: 10000px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="story" id="part1">
        Part 1 of story
        <a href="#part2" id="button1">Click Here to go to Part 2</a>
    </div>

    <div class="story" id="part2">
        Part 2 of story
        <a href="#part1" id="button2">Click Here to go to Part 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```